# Syntax error in awk $(NF-1) - NF-1 command not found

Tags: unix, awk

```
for INSTANCE in $INSTANCES
do
  ssh weblogic@${SERVER} "egrep \"^$SEARCHHOUR1:$SEARCHMIN1.*DEBUG.*LONG QUERY.* ms.\$|^$SEARCHHOUR2:$SEARCHMIN2.*DEBUG.*LONG QUERY.* ms.\$\" vgprod1/mw.log.$INSTANCE  | awk '{ $(NF-1)>=10000 }' "
done
```

Error:

```
NF-1: command not found
awk: cmd. line:1: { >=10000 }
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error
```

I am getting the above error while executing on a Unix server. I guess I am missing backslash at some places in AWK. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by *sarathi*, your problem is an unquoted `$`.

It might be easier to spot if you split up the command:

```
pattern="^$SEARCHHOUR1:$SEARCHMIN1.*DEBUG.*LONG QUERY.* ms.\$|^$SEARCHHOUR2:$SEARCHMIN2.*DEBUG.*LONG QUERY.* ms.\$"

for INSTANCE in $INSTANCES
do
  ssh weblogic@${SERVER} "egrep '$pattern' vgprod1/mw.log.$INSTANCE  | awk '\$(NF-1) > 1000'"
done
```

Also note that `egrep '$pattern'` will be expanded correctly when it is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: It removes the error but does not get me the required records whereas if I check I find 3 records are present. I want to get (awk) the records where the 2nd last column is greater than 1000.

Comment: @RameshRoutray: In your example you test if it is greater than 10000. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: No. No. that's not a problem. I have done that for different numbers time and again. The command itself runs well and gives me the required records. But when I add `ssh` part to it, it does not recognize `NF-1` as a variable. And I think that's the problem. See my other comment @sarathi.

Comment: @ramesh remove the braces around the condition. They change the awk script meaning. Note that in the working example you give in another comment you have no braces.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski: Well spotted.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski thanks bro.. braces were the real culprit here.. Now it's done. thanks@Thor

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `$` sign as below:

`\$` in `awk '{ \$(NF-1)....`

Comment: It's true that modifying the code as per your suggestion removes the error. But @sarathi, I don't achieve my objective. In fact I want to get the records where the 2nd last column is greater than 1000. But it gets zero records whereas I checked using egrep|awk that 3 records present for the criteria.

Comment: @ramesh Then perhaps you are expecting another column instead of `NF-1`. Check it first by doing a simple awk print on the data. You might need to change the `IFS` as per your need.

Comment: @sarathi I have already done so. Now the scenario is that if I do `egrep "^06:0.*DEBUG.*LONG QUERY.* ms.$|^06:1.*DEBUG.*LONG QUERY.* ms.$" "$FILE" | awk '$(NF-1)>=1000' > grep_ramesh.txt` I receive the required records. But when I add `ssh` part beforeit, there arises the problem.

Comment: thanks@sarathi . two things I did. removed the braces and added the escape for `$` as you suggested `\$`.